# Detect is python program run with python or python3

Tags: python

I have a python program that can be run both: with `python` or `python3`:

```
# that
python app.py

# or that
python3 app.py
```

How to detect inside `app.py` program which command was used?
I tried to use `sys.argv`, but it doesn't contains such info.
Any ideas?

Comment: You could use `sys.version_info` at the top of the file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [`sys.version_info`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.version_info), specifically `sys.version_info.major`, which should be 2 or 3, respectively.

A different way is using the [`six`](https://six.readthedocs.io/) package, with the booleans `six.PY2` and `six.PY3`. This package should give other useful utilities for 2/3 compatibility.

Answer (score 3):

```py
import sys

print(sys.version)
```